# Save PDF as a blob in a database using PHP?

Tags: php, database, pdf, blob

I have a PDF file on my server that I want to select and transform into a blob for insertion into my database (using an `INSERT INTO` command). My first problem is getting hold of the PDF using PHP. I know it is done with the `file_get_contents()` function, but I do not understand what parameters it needs.

Comment: Have you read the documentations? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Add the code you've attempted and the specific error(s) you're seeing. Some effort is required and will help bring in more useful answers.

Comment: Grammar tidy up, mainly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fp = fopen($fileLocation, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($fileLocation));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

You can save the $content to blob field in mysql

Comment: After I did that I can just do this?:
$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO costumer(costumer_pdf) VALUES (?)"); 
$statement->bind_param("s", $content);
$statement->execute();

Comment: @Frank yes you can directly insert this into database